Avast Antivirus blocks Salesforce CLI when authorizing an org
My antivirus, avast, blocks my Salesforce CLI when I'm trying to authorize a new org.
It gives me this error message:
We've blocked powershell.exe because it was infected with IDP.HELU.PSE41 - Command line detection

I did the following:

Adding this directory to the Avast ignored list


Updating the PowerShell to the latest version


The only workaround I have right now is to disable the anti-virus when I authorize an org and then re-enable it.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Two questions: Have you tried with good old cmd.exe? What gives you the confidence to say that this is a false positive?

When I use Terminal: Select Default Profile and set it to cmd.exe, I get this error -
Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org
18:06:33.334 sf org:login:web --alias test --instance-url https://test.salesforce.com --set-default
Error (1): Cannot start the OAuth redirect server on port 1717.
Try this:
Kill the process running on port 1717 or use a custom connected app and update OauthLocalPort in the sfdx-project.json file.
18:06:34.158 sf org:login:web --alias test --instance-url https://test.salesforce.com --set-default
ended with exit code 1

I followed the instructions on this post - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256860/authorize-org-failed-in-vs-code
The error I mentioned did not happen again but I did get THE SAME error I got when I ran it on PowerShell (the one I started the post with).
And about your other questions - How do I know it's false-positive - I don't... I just assume Salesforce CLI is reliable and not infected lol maybe I'm wrong
